# C++ SFML Font loading problems

Tags: c++, sfml

I am having problems with loading my `miranda.ttf` file. I have the file in the same directory as `main.cc` and I am sure I am typing it the right way, but it still doesn't work for some reason. I have tried multiple other fonts without luck.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "core/headers/util.hpp"
#include "core/headers/ui.hpp"
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600, 32U), L"Kolonie Mravenců", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    sf::CircleShape circle;
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    circle.setPosition(10, 10);
    circle.setRadius(6);
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("miranda.ttf")){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setPosition(sf::Vector2<float>(200.0f, 600.0f / 2.0f));
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(227, 227, 227));
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code of `main.cc`.

I am executing the code using terminal in VS Code Insiders on a Macbook Air.

Comment: Having files in the same directory as the source files, or even the executable file, doesn't matter unless the running programs [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is set to that location.

Comment: These fonts are not compiled into the exe. So just having them with the main.cc file won't do any good. You need to have it in the directory where you execute the program.

Comment: It seemed to me that he just created font object, but hadn't load from file font in this object, just wrote an statement for that!